# Function definition and delayed assignment

Tags: functions, function-construction, wavelet-analysis

I need to define the following function

```
MyWavelet[n_]["PrimalLowpass", prec_ : MachinePrecision] := 
   Table[(-1)^(j - 1) h[[2*n - j]], {j, 0, 2*n - 1}]
```

which depends on the following code

```
num = T;
precis = 32;
p[n_, x_] := Sum[ Binomial[n-1+j,j]*x^j, {j,0,n-1}]
pol[n_, z_] := Expand[z^(n-1) * p[n, (1 - (z + 1/z)/2)/2]]
roo[n_] := NSolve[pol[n, x] ==0, x, precis]
absgreater[x1_, x2_] := Abs[x1] < Abs[x2]
sroo[n_] := Sort[roo[n], absgreater]
insidehalf[n_] := Take[sroo[n], n-1]

rootlist = x /. insidehalf[num];
prod = Expand[Product[(w - rootlist[[j]]), {j, 1, num - 1}]];
normalizer = prod 2^(num - 1/2) /. w -> 1;
polyn = Expand[(1 + w)^num * prod/normalizer];
h = Reverse[N[CoefficientList[polyn, w], precis]];
```

where T is an integer.

My problem is I need to replace `num` with the value of `n` when calling the `MyWavelet` function and then dynamically evaluate, so I can get the `h` table values assigned to the specific `MyWavelet[n]`.

I tried couple o'times using `With, but with no success.

Comment: The `Length` of `h` appears to be `2num`. You could feed `h` to `MyWavelet` and derive `n` from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try specifying your function as `MyWavelet[n_,opts:OptionsPattern[]]` [(documentation)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OptionsPattern.html) and define `Options` to your function `Method->"PrimalLowpass",Precision->$MachinePrecision`, like this:

```
Options[MyWavelet] ={Method->"PrimalLowpass",Precision->$MachinePrecision}
```

To actually construct all this as a function, you need to put certain steps as a `Module`, and some outside as auxiliary functions. First you will need to do this:

```
Clear[rootlist, prod, normalizer, polyn, h]
```

Then something like the following should work. Notice how I've cascaded the use of `prec` to some of the auxiliary functions and made them two-parameter functions. Because `prec` is used as a parameter in the definition of `rootlist`, it needs to be outside that set of `Module` definitions. If I had not put the definition of `rootlist` inside the curly braces defining the names of modularized variables, i.e. I had written `Module[{rootlist, prod...},rootlist= x/.insidehalf[n,prec]`, this wouldn't have been necessary.

```
p[n_, x_] := Sum[Binomial[n - 1 + j, j]*x^j, {j, 0, n - 1}]    
pol[n_, z_] := Expand[z^(n - 1)*p[n, (1 - (z + 1/z)/2)/2]]   
roo[n_, prec_] := NSolve[pol[n, x] == 0, x, prec]
absgreater[x1_, x2_] := Abs[x1] < Abs[x2] 
sroo[n_, prec_] := Sort[roo[n, prec], absgreater]   
insidehalf[n_, prec_] := Take[sroo[n, prec], n - 1]

MyWavelet[n_Integer?Positive, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 With[{prec = OptionValue[Precision]},
  Module[{rootlist = x /. insidehalf[n, prec], prod, normalizer, 
    polyn, h, w},
   prod = Expand[Product[(w - rootlist[[j]]), {j, 1, n - 1}]];
   normalizer = prod 2^(n - 1/2) /. w -> 1;
   polyn = Expand[(1 + w)^n*prod/normalizer];
   h = Reverse[N[CoefficientList[polyn, w], prec]];
   Table[(-1)^(j - 1) h[[2*n - j]], {j, 0, 2*n - 1}]
   ]]
```

Note that you have small imaginary parts that you might not want:

```
MyWavelet[3, Precision -> 32]

  {-0.03522629188570953660274066471551 + 
  0.*10^-33 I, -0.0854412738820266616928191691818 + 0.*10^-33 I, 
 0.1350110200102545886963899066994 + 0.*10^-32 I, 
 0.4598775021184915700951519421476 + 
  0.*10^-32 I, -0.8068915093110925764944936040887 + 0.*10^-32 I, 
 0.3326705529500826159985115891390 + 0.*10^-33 I}
```

You can get rid of them using  `Chop`.

By the way, the `Method` doesn't currently do anything, but I assume this is a cut-down version of the real problem.

Comment: I made one small change - you were using the OP's symbol `precis`, where I suspect you wanted your symbol `prec` scoped by your `With` statement.

Comment: Is there any specific reason that you're using number `$MachinePrecision` (which might be nice, if you want the precision tracked), rather than the symbol `MachinePrecision` (which might be nice, if you want speed)?

Comment: The problem is the values I obtain and assign to the specific MyWavelet[n] are not a valid wavelet specification, i.e. {{0,val0},{1,val1},{2,val2},{3,val3}} for n = 2. I need to make this work so I can plot the mother and father functions, which I was unable to do using the old "change-everything-by-hand" method.

Comment: Thanks @MarkMcClure  - stupid typo from answering too quickly! No specific reason I used `$MachinePrecision`, might have just used the one I remembered.